# wubi install of ubuntu 12.10 on hp dv6 6154tx causes uncontrolled heating, fan speed, low battery life

Tags: 12.10, ati, dv6

i have a hp dv6 6154tx with an integrated Intel GPU and a discrete ATI GPU (Radeon Mobility HD 6490M (1 GB DDR5)).

-Problems:

1. when i install ubuntu 12.10 using wubi, my laptop starts heating, fans start to run fast (to much of noise), and battery goes really low
2. Any attempt to install catalyst drivers (from ati official site and also proprietary drivers) fails , as after reboot when i login everything is gone like no unity no desktop and sometimes black screen appears.
   even bumblebee and jupiter didnt help....  :(

So PLEASE, PLEASE can somebody post the real solution to my problems i.e.(inc battery life and stop fan noise and heating).
(i want to install ubuntu only using wubi)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the latest drivers from AMD cannot still be used with 12.10. The X server version of 12.10 is too new and the drivers still don't support it.

If your laptop is overheating you need to install 12.04 and use the proprietary drivers, that will cool it down.

There are other solutions out there: downgrade X to a version supported by the drivers is one, I would not recommend this though. You need to install 12.04 with the proprietary drivers or you need to wait until AMD releases drivers that support the X version of Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Hi @BrunoPereira, thx for replying,                              
about ubuntu 12.04(i had it before installing 12.10), when i installed the proprietary drivers the 3d effects in ubuntu 12.04 seemed to have disappeared, i was no longer able to customize unity.... 
and what are ur opinions about using vga_switcheroo for this problem.....